# I can't find a regex for this Regular Expression

Tags: regex

I am not very good with regular expressions, and I just have a simple question here.

I have a list of links in this way:

```
http://domain.com/andrei/sometext
http://domain2.com/someothertext/sometextyouknow/whoknows
http://domain341.com/text/thisisit/haha
```

I just want two regular expressions, to take this out:

```
http://domain.com/andrei/
http://domain2.com/someothertext/
http://domain341.com/text/
```

This is the first regex that I need, and I need another regex only to take out the domain, but I guess I'll figure that out if somebody could tell me the regex to take out only what I wrote.

Comment: Depending on what language you are using, it's probably better to let the built-in path parsing library take care of it.

Comment: Love the title - it is like a zen koan.

Comment: I have tried this, but takes out the entire link: http://([^/].*[^/])

Answer (score 5):

This is what you (most likely) need:

```
[a-z]+://([^/ ]+)(?:/[^/ ]*/?)?
```

Here's how it works:

1. `[a-z]+` part is for protocol name (this means, "1 or more letters" - it will match http/https/file/ftp/gopher/foo/whatever protocol, but if you want to match only "http" you can write it explicitly)
2. `://` is literally what it says ;)
3. `[^/ ]+` is one or more non-slash and non-space character. it can be "a", can be fqdn, can be ip address. whatever
4. `(?:/[^/ ]*/?)?` - this one is more complicated. The `?` in the end means that this whole thing in parentheses may or may not be there (it is optional). `?:` immediately inside parentheses means *do not reuse this sub-pattern* (it is not assigned a number and cannot be re-used later by that number). `[^/ ]*` means 0 or more non-slash non-space characters, and the question mark after the trailing slash, again, states that the slash is optional.

Overall, this ensures matches for things like this:

```
http://foo/bar/baz/something -> http://foo/bar/
http://hello.world.example.com/ -> http://hello.world.example.com/
http://foo.net -> http://foo.net
ftp://ftp.mozilla.org/pub -> ftp://ftp.mozilla.org/pub
```

NOTE #1: I did not use escaping for forward slashes **intentionally** to make the expression more readable, so make sure you use some other character as a `delimiter`, OR escape all the appearances of `/` - use `\/` instead.

NOTE #2: Add `i` modifier if you want the expression to be case-insensitive (`a-z` will not match caps), and `g` modifier if you want to make multiple matches in one big block of text.

In the matches, subpattern 0 will be the whole matched thing, and subpattern 1 - only hostname

Answer (score 1):

This is probably what you are looking for:

`([a-zA-Z]+://([\w.]*)/(?:.*?/)?)`

You have all the match in the group 1 and just the domain in the group 2. No need for 2 regular expressions. :)

Answer (score 0):

Use regex `https?:\/\/[^\/]+\/[^\/]+/(.*)` for your first task - replace `$1` with emtpy string `''`.

Use regex `https?:\/\/([^\/]+)` for your second task - a match `$1` is the domain name.